# How to store image in Property.Settings.Default?

Tags: c#, .net, image, settings.settings

How can I store an image in `Property.Settings.Default`?

What Datatype I should use?

Comment: You can use object or custom type.

Comment: Sorry, but I am not getting what do you want to say.. Can you please describe?

Comment: There is an option of `Browse` in settings to choose custom type. You may try `byte`

Comment: Yeah. I can convert Image in byte array but how can I set type as byte array. Please suggest me way to store and retrieve if I use byte data type.

Comment: Do you really need it to be in the settings file? Using an image as a embedded ressource should be better and easier if that`s an option for you

Comment: Can you convert your image to Base64String?

Comment: Yes, I can covert bytes array to String.

Comment: @NJBhanushali I have post my answer, check it.

Comment: What is the *real* problem you are trying to solve? Images aren't *settings* and shouldn't be stored as such. Images are typically stored as *resources* or *content*. A setting may be the path to the image but not the image itself

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var base64 = string.Empty;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
   yourImage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
   base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
}
```

Create string variable from settings file eg. `MyImage`

```
Properties.Settings.Default.MyImage = base64;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

EDIT:

```
pictureBox1.Image = GetImage(Properties.Settings.Default.MyImage);
public Image GetImage(string value)
{        
    byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(value);
    Image image;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        image = Image.FromStream(ms);
    }
    return image;
}
```

Comment: Yeah. Above code save image to Properties.Settings.Default. Thank you.
How can I covert Properties.Settings.Default.MyImage back into Image and save in PictureBox?

Comment: Note: converting an image to base64 will make it 33% larger

Comment: Yes, we should always try to store images into local disk instead of database or into settings etc.

Comment: @Roy T., I will keep your suggest in my mind. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

As I already commented earlier: it`s better to use ressources.
Here is a guideline for using embedded ressources:

Go to the Resources tab instead of the Settings tab and add the image from there. If you don't already have a default resource file created click the link and one will be created for you. 
[image: Embed]
Select "Images" for the type of
resource (from the drop-down above) and then add an existing resource (from the adjacent drop-down).

You can access the resource
from your program using the following code (static class `Properties.Resource`):

```
Bitmap image = Properties.Resources.MyJPGImage;
```

You can also access ressources via reflections from other assemblies.. try to take a look at a full example for that (including Images) at [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/319292)

Comment: this is not really what's asked... if you store an image as resource you cannot change it at run time and store it.
Settings.settings allows you to store and save item as an .xml file, then retrieve it and change it at run time.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that by default (the editor doesn't let you pick a `byte[]` as data type). You can edit the XML from the settings file to include a byte array. You can serialize and deserialize that again at your end.

If you want to set a default in the settings file, you need to supply a base64 encoded string.

This would be the required format for the setting in the Settings file:

```
<Setting Name="Setting" Type="System.Byte[]" mimetype="application/x-microsoft.net.object.bytearray.base64" Scope="User">
  <Value Profile="(Default)">
    iVBOR...
  </Value>
</Setting>
```

Only use this option if you really have to. If possible, just save the path to the file in your settings, and save the file externally, in a data folder besides your settings for example.

Comment: Images should be stored as resources, not settings and VS has an editor for just that. I suspect the OP faces the XY problem - thinking that settings are the answer to whatever the real problem is and getting into trouble

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos True, but what if you've loaded the users profile image from an external source? You have to save it somewhere. The settings can be an option, maybe not the best, but possible.

Comment: Never in settings - it's *not* a setting. A file would be preferable, or even a BLOB field in the user's profile table. Settings are supposed to be easily editable. Storing a blob into settings requires quite a bit of code to *load* it into the XML file in the first place. Storing the *path* to an image's path makes more sense

Comment: When it comes to XML handling the .NET framework generally load the entire file in memory and, then, try to locate what you're looking for. If that settings file isn't meant to be created as per user basis, you'll regret storing images into it very soon.

Comment: @RubensFarias that's not quite true. .NET will use whatever method you tell it to (XmlReader vs XmlDocument etc), but *all settings* are *deserialized* in memory as Settings objects. They are settings after all, not data. It doesn't make sense to load them partially, or reload them while the application is running